# how to add 2 background images on the sides of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage which is big enough to be scrolled down. I want to divide my body element like so:

- 1/4 (possibly less) of the body section on the left should be an image. If the image itself doesn't cover the page's height i should have more images just like it below it.
- 2/4 of the page should retain its original background-color property so that the content (which is centered) is clearly visible.
- The remaining 1/4 of the page should be just like i described in the first dot.

If i use the background-image property for my body section i get images that stack on one another, when i actually want them to be as i described, from left to right, and covering the entire height of the page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add two background images - left and right from center column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068260/how-to-add-two-background-images-left-and-right-from-center-column)

Comment: I'll see if it answers my question. Sorry if it is indeed a duplicate, but it's difficult to phrase this question correctly, and i couldn't find the answer :/

Comment: Duplicates are not bad things, to me. If it is marked as a duplicate, it will serve as a "signpost" pointing to the answer, which should help everyone, including people searching using phrases like those in your question.

Comment: That does make sense! Nice :)